# What is the percent flattening in Haumea?

Tags: dwarf-planets

I've recently noticed that in Wikipedia articles such as Pluto ([Link](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pluto)), there's this number that says how much flattened it is ([Definition Here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Haumea)). In Pluto, it's >1%.

Haumea, which is a very flattened dwarf planet, actually doesn't have this information on Wikipedia, and I haven't been able to find it online.

It would be great if someone could find this info (and it's source as well), because I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be because Haumea is a Triaxial ellipsoid. It's dimensions are different in every cardinal direction. The term 'flattening' only makes sense for the biaxial ellipsoids, because two of the axes are the same and one is different (in the case of Pluto, the equatorial axis is 1% larger, hence 1% flattened). The concept of 'flattened' doesn't make terribly much sense when all three axes are different.

Haumea's axis ratios are approximately 1 : 0.75 : 0.5, if that's the information you're after.

Comment: That makes way more sense! Is that why there's no specific dimensions?